# How can I put a Binwalk extracted firmware back into a .bin binary file?

Tags: firmware

So, I extracted my router's binary file with binwalk and got the filesystem. I made some changes to the WebUI of the router, and now I want to put it back together into a .bin file so that I can flash my router with it. How do I go about it?

Answer (score 1):

According to the main developer of Binwalk, [you can't and this is not a feature they will implement anytime soon](https://github.com/devttys0/binwalk/issues/215). From the link:

> This isn't a binwalk related question, as binwalk does not re-build binary images. However, you might want to take a look at the firmware mod kit, which uses binwalk for extraction and can re-build many router firmware images automatically (it may even work on this particular firmware): https://code.google.com/archive/p/firmware-mod-kit/

Now unfortunately, *firmware-mod-kit* hasn't been updated for a while, but is probably your closest bet. Otherwise, you may want to use the output of *binwalk* and try to "cut and paste" original and modified sections of the firmware file using the [dd](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/dd.1.html). Note that this will likely work only with very simple firmware images, as anything with checksums and sections/file length will have to be modified manually. I was able to make it happen in very limited cases where the firmware was mostly a header with a file system appended to it.