# How to repack reverse-engineered router firmware?

Tags: firmware

I managed to unpack the filesystem contents of a TP-Link router `.bin` file using `binwalk`, `dd` and `unsquashfs`. The squash FS was at the end of the bin file, the part before having a relatively large lzma archive.

Now I would like to make changes to the filesystem and repack the firmware file back. How can I achieve this? How do I know whether I need to attach a checksum or similar?

This question is different from [How can I put a Binwalk extracted firmware back into a .bin binary file?](https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/13262/how-can-i-put-a-binwalk-extracted-firmware-back-into-a-bin-binary-file) in that it's vendor specific, `firmware-mod-kit` is a not preferred option (unless it's the only one...) and it contains an extra question

Comment: "a TP-Link router" is not being very specific for a supposedly device-specific question.  In general terms, read up on how to pack a squashfs (don't forget that the permissions need to come out right).  As for a checksum, you could try without and see what happens.  Hopefully you've done a flash dump before starting.  Sometimes physically replacing the chip is worth the few minutes it takes.

Comment: @ChrisStratton flash dump is for in case I mess up or what? I don't have a second chip to it with in the first place apparently.